# Use webforms to search and edit information from a custom table on the database

Tags: 7, database, webforms

I am attempting to search and edit information by using 2 webforms. The custom table is found in the database that my Drupal project is using and is named "test_update." It has 2 records on the table.

The webforms are:

1.**Edit Search customer**

[image: Search form which redirects to Update/Edit customer form if the record was found]

The user inputs the name which to retrieve the wanted information. A select query is executed using the value captured by the user to identify the record when the webform is submitted.

- If the record is identified, it redirects to the **Update/Edit Customer** webform and displays the values on the respective textfields. **Example :** **Richard** was found from the table on the database. Since the record was found, the information **"Name: Richard" and "Surname: Warwick" are displayed on the **Update/Edit Customer** webform.**
- If it is not identified, it displays a message and redirects to the
  "**Edit Search customer**" webform.

2.**Update/edit customer**

[image: The form is used to edit existing customer details displayed on the fields. The details are then saved when the webform is submitted]

The displayed values on the fields can then be edited. When the webform is submitted, all changes are then saved to the table.

I added the following codes in the **webform.module** file. They are found inside the **function webform_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission)** :

```
$accessnode=$node->nid;
if($accessnode==8) //nid of the eidt search customer form is 8, if this webform is selected
{
    $searchByName=$submission->data[1]['value'];

    //select query
    $result=db_query("SELECT * FROM {test_update} WHERE name = :name",array(':name'=>$searchByName))->fetchAll(); 

    if(!(empty($result)))
    {
        //redirect to webform with nid 7 (Update/Edit Customer webform)
        //Use the result set to display the values to the webform with nid 7 ()
        //on submit, it updates and saves the data into the table from the Update/Edit customer webform


    }
    else
    {
        //display error message and redirects to the search page
        drupal_set_message(t('The customer does not exist. Try again'), 'error'); 
        header('Refresh: 5;url=http://localhost/babyDrupal/node/8');// Aim: redirect after 5 secs to the search edit form, Result: it doesn't redirect to the page

    }

}
```

Can I have some help on how I can acheive this please?